# How to restore Parse data after migrate to a own mongo?

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to migrate mongo parse to my mongo, but I have lost my mongo and the parse data.

Have a way to restore the parse data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on **finalize** on parse.com when migrated the DB, i think you cant go back